# How to send BCH programmatically using existing wallet

Tags: api, bitcoin-cash, sending, cash

*I'm a completely newbie to crypto so sorry in advance for stupid question.*
How can I send BCH to desired address using existing wallet?

I found few services with quite nice rest API or even ready libraries for few different languages but all of them require creating new wallet in their platform.

Assuming I have my own wallet and private key for it, is there any way I can transfer BCH to other specified by me wallet **programmatically**? It can be literally anything - rest api, node/python/php library, etc.

Monitoring transactions seems to by quite popular thing and no problem here but I found barely no information regarding sending BCH (especially from existing wallet) on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

There's [BTCD](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd), a famous BTC library in Golang, which can be used with [bchutil](https://github.com/cpacia/bchutil) to code for BCH.

You just use BTCD as you would normally, and use bchutil for TX signing, CashAddr, etc.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/decred/atomicswap/blob/78a2e23/cmd/bchatomicswap/main.go#L901)

EDIt: this answer is now outdated. Instead, use https://github.com/gcash/bchd BCHD as a drop-in replacement to btcd. You can just search for btcd tutorials and apply the same steps using the bchd library.